# Python Dictionary Methods behaving diff for 2.7.6 and 3.3 version

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I was using python dictionary built-in methods and found they behave a bit differently in terms of giving the output on 2.7 and 3.3 version of Python.

Here is an example:

Let my dictionary be the following:

```
d = {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': "Hello", 'C': ["this is good"]}

>>> d
{'B': 'Hello', 'C': ['this is good'], 'A': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Now when I use the `keys()` or `items()` or `values()` method in 3.3 it is giving me the following output:

```
>>> print(d.keys())
dict_keys(['B', 'C', 'A'])

>>> print(d.values())
dict_values(['Hello', ['this is good'], [1, 2, 3]])

>>> print(d.items())
dict_items([('B', 'Hello'), ('C', ['this is good']), ('A', [1, 2, 3])])
```

While ideally it should give me a list of the keys or values or items as given by 2.7 version below:

```
>>> print(d.keys())
['A', 'C', 'B']

>>> print(d.values())
[[1, 2, 3], ['this is good'], 'Hello']

>>> print(d.items())
[('A', [1, 2, 3]), ('C', ['this is good']), ('B', 'Hello')]
```

I see that in the help on `dict.keys()` or `dict.values` on 3.3 it now says it returns a set of keys. unlike a list of keys on 2.7

My problem is that since it is also appending `dict_keys` or `dict_values` or `dict_items` keywords in the output I am unable to use the list of keys or values or items to store it in some variable in 3.3 unlike in 2.7

Can anyone help on this why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: It is not without reason that one is called `2.x` and the other is called `3.x` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 3 switched to using more efficient data structures and methods throughout; you can get the same [dictionary view objects](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) in Python 2 with using [`dict.viewkeys()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys), [`dict.viewvalues()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewvalues) and [`dict.viewitems()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewitems).

If you have to have a list, simply use `list()` to turn collect all values in the view into a list:

```
>>> d={'A': [1,2,3], 'B': "Hello", 'C': ["this is good"]}
>>> d.keys()
dict_keys(['C', 'B', 'A'])
>>> list(d.keys())
['C', 'B', 'A']
>>> list(d.values())
[['this is good'], 'Hello', [1, 2, 3]]
>>> list(d.items())
[('C', ['this is good']), ('B', 'Hello'), ('A', [1, 2, 3])]
```

For just the keys, you can also call `list()` on the dictionary, *directly*:

```
>>> list(d)
['C', 'B', 'A']
```